# put $(SolutionDir)\packages\ in .csproj file instead of ..\packages\

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, .net-4.5

I have a solution with some class libraries that are used in multiple other projects. When I do an `Install-Package` from VS it will take `$(SolutionDir)\packages\` and translate that into a relative path, for example `..\packages\`. This is then saved into the `.csproj` files.

My problem is that these .csproj files are used in different locations with different file hierarchies, meaning that `..\packages\` will not point to `$(SolutionDir)\packages\` in some other solutions. So the question is, how do I get it to write `$(SolutionDir)\packages\` into the `.csproj` files instead of `..\packages\`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get NuGet to write $(SolutionDir)\packages into the project files. You would need to modify its source code.

What NuGet provides is a way for multiple solutions to share a common packages directory by defining this directory in a [NuGet.Config file](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file).

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="SomeDirectory\Packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

You can put this NuGet.config file in a directory that is a common parent to the solutions and then NuGet will find it and use it for the solutions.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that can be used is that you keep all your solutions at one level. That way packages folder would be at same level for all solutions/projects.

Comment: Unless you have only a handful of solutions, keeping all solutions at one level may be impractical. Though I don't have that many, even my handful (a few dozen solutions) is easier to handle with the solutions stored in a hierarchy.